# UINavigationBar Scrolling behaviour is not working properly

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

`UINavigationBar` `scrolling` `appearance` behaviour is not working properly in one screen where i use `UITableView` within `UIStackView`. In other screens where Only `UITableView` used there Scrolling behaviour is working properly and ***underLine separator*** is visible.

- Without `UIStackView`, where **navigationBar** working properly

> Screen's visible design in the Device.

[image: WithouUIStackView]

> `StoryBoard` UI of above screenshot, Games Screen.

[image: UIStoryBoard]

As above *ScreenShot* when we scroll to `Top Edge`, there's a **visible underline** to the `NavigationBar`.

- `UITableView` within `UIStackView`, where I'm getting issue

> **StoryBoard Interface**

[image: LibraryVC StoryBoard]

> When i set `UIStackView.top = superview.top`

[image: Transparent Nav]

> When i set `UIStackView.top = safeArea.top`

[image: Hard white Nav]

- **I've applied multiple solutions from Various source, but none of Any is working for me.**

> Also tried below solutions.

1. [tab navigation bar changes after upgrading to xcode 13 ios 15](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69281380/tab-navigation-bar-changes-after-upgrading-to-xcode-13-ios-15)
2. [iOS 15 Navigation Bar Transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69111478/ios-15-navigation-bar-transparent)
3. [Navigation bar is transparent when scrolling starts in iOS15 only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69119009/navigation-bar-is-transparent-when-scrolling-starts-in-ios15-only)
4. [Transparent iOS navigation bar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25845855/transparent-ios-navigation-bar)
5. [iOS 15 Navigation Bar Transparent issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69943071/ios-15-navigation-bar-transparent-issue)

Comment: Read the docs for [`UINavigationBar scrollEdgeAppearance`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationbar/3198027-scrolledgeappearance?language=objc). The difference you see in your two cases is that the first has a scroll view (a table view is a scroll view). You don't have a scrollview in your stack view setup.

Comment: @HangarRash I've updated screenshot, Now u can see? Scrollview within stackview

Comment: But the the scroll view isn't the view controller's view. You just need to set the nav bar's `standardAppearance` to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've resolved the issue by changing order of the controls stack, just putted `UITableView` **outSide** of the `UIStackView` and it's working perfectly as expected.

- **`UIStoryBoard`**

[image: StoryBoard]

- **Layout visibility**

[image: Visible Layout]